# Retrofit Unable to Parse JSON from Model Class

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to show this JSON in my app using retrofit by network calls.
Sample data:

```
{
    total: 17727,
    total_pages: 1773,
    results: [ 
        {
            id: "qX9Ie7ieb1E",
            created_at: "2016-01-26T08:17:45-05:00",
            updated_at: "2018-05-18T13:04:07-04:00",
            width: 4956,
            height: 3304,
            color: "#101617",
            description: "Neon mural of woman wearing sunglasses and pink lipstick on brick wall in England",
            urls: { raw: "", regular: "", full: "", small:"", thumb:""}
        }, 
        {}, {}, ...
    ]
}
```

I have created the interface like below:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("search/photos")
    Call<ImagesResponse> getImages(
        @Query("client_id") String clientId,
        @Query("order_by") String orderBy,
        @Query("query") String query,
        @Query("page") int pageIndex
    );

}
```

and the api:

```
public class UnsplashImageApi {

    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .build();
    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient() {
        if (retrofit != null) {
            return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getOkHttpClient())
                .baseUrl(Constants.UNSPLASH_BASE_URL)
                .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

The model class is structured based on the response like below:

```
public class ImagesResponse {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("total")
    private Integer total;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    private Integer totalPages;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("results")
    private List<Results> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Omitted getters and setters for brevity. The `Results` class is shown like this:

```
public class Results {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String imageId;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("raw")
    public String rawImg;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("full")
    public String fullImg;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("regular")
    public String regularImg;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("small")
    public String smallImg;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("thumb")
    public String thumbImg;

    public boolean isFavorite;
```

In my fragment, I have tried calling the `ApiService` to load first page data like below:

```
apiService = UnsplashImageApi.getRetrofitClient().create(ApiService.class);
loadFirstPage();
```

but the app crashes on this line `getRetrofitClient().create()` with this error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object retrofit2.Retrofit.create(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference
    at com.jjoey.walpy.fragments.ArtFragment.onCreateView(ArtFragment.java:70)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
```

I have omitted the code to load the first page as it's not the source of concern here. Can anyone please explain to me why it's crashing and with a possible solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written that `retrofit != null` within the if condition.

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(){
    if (retrofit != null) { // Check this line
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getOkHttpClient())
                .baseUrl(Constants.UNSPLASH_BASE_URL)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

You have to write `retrofit == null` within the if condition. Otherwise, Retrofit will not get initialized.

The very first-time Retrofit is null and you have checked `retrofit != null` then. That's why the code within the if condition bypassed and it's creating the Null Pointer Exception as you are calling `create()` method from a non-initialized instance of Retrofit.

Modified code will be:

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(){
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getOkHttpClient())
                .baseUrl(Constants.UNSPLASH_BASE_URL)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for detailed explanation. It works now but how do I access the urls in the Results class, it shows only placeholder image. Thanks

Comment: NB: This answer is still incomplete for a singleton pattern as it does not cache the initialised retrofit object, therefore `retrofit` is always `null`. While it may work, a new retrofit object is created each time `getRetrofitClient()` is called.

Comment: @veritas1 Ok. I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a NPE because your singleton logic is incorrect. Adjusted version below:

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(){
    if (null == retrofit){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getOkHttpClient())
                .baseUrl(Constants.UNSPLASH_BASE_URL)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```